# How do log out of Twitter in Safari?

Tags: safari

this is taking me more minutes than it should be, i can't log out of twitter. I'm using safari browser on an apple computer. UGH. can't twitter make this easier? it says you should go to "Me" tab and look for a gear icon but when i go to "Me" there is no icon.
I tried going to settings but still there is no option or icon that says "log out".
This should be simple but twitter is making this confusing.

Comment: How is this an Apple problem and not a Twitter problem?

Comment: I don't think this is very specific to Apple or Safari, it's just a Twitter glitch.

Answer (score 2):

Just click on your profile picture on the right of the search field and choose the last menu item (*Log out*)

[image]